# When trying to push changes, the error "The specified changeset 6 can't be found." what does this mean and how to solve it?

Tags: plasticscm

Tell me how to solve this error, since I don't quite understand what he wants from me.
[This Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aKu9.jpg)

Comment: It seems the workspace selector was pointing to a changeset that doesn't exist anymore. You may need to undo the changes so the workspace selector is pointing again to an existing changeset. If you have pending changes you don't want to lose, please create a backup for them first so you can apply it later.